# Map Navigator for iOS

Tags: ios, dictionary, navigator, ios6

(I'm not a iOS dev, just need to know it for a concept) is it possible to have a navigation system the same like the maps app have it *whitout* leaving the my own map-app that uses the google maps inside. And will it be possible to use the turnbyturn navigation in iOS6 and the new Vector map *inside* of my own map-app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use the official Maps app for turn-by-turn. You can draw paths on the MKMapView but would need to supply your own data.